# Copy paste column range using OpenPyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

Hi so I am trying to copy and paste W7:W46 column into another worksheet. The code I have so far,

```
col_j = New_Burden['W']
for idx, cell in enumerate(col_j,1):
    ws1.cell(row = idx, column = 10).value = cell.value
```

is able to copy over the entire column, but unfortunately transfers the various headers as well. One solution I have tried is:

```
for row in New_Burden['W7:W46']:
    for cell in row:
        ws1.cell(row = 2, column = 10).value = cell.value
```

But that only copies the first value of W7

Comment: Where do you get `idx`?

Comment: @frankyjuang idx is just a variable name.

Comment: Because `row` and `column` don't chane.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copy a Range(`['W7:W46']`) from one Worksheet to another Worksheet:
If the Ranges are **not** overlapping, it's also possible in the same Worksheet.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
# Create a new Workbook
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.worksheets[0]

from openpyxl.utils import range_boundaries
# Define start Range(['J2']) in the new Worksheet
min_col, min_row, max_col, max_row = range_boundaries('J2')

# Iterate Range you want to copy
for row, row_cells in enumerate(New_Burden['W7:W46'], min_row):
    for column, cell in enumerate(row_cells, min_col):
        # Copy Value from Copy.Cell to given Worksheet.Cell
        ws.cell(row=row, column=column).value = cell.value
```

---

If you want to do the above with multiple different Columns, 
use the above in a `function`:

```
def copy_range(source_range, target_start):
    # Define start Range(target_start) in the new Worksheet
    min_col, min_row, max_col, max_row = range_boundaries(target_start)

    # Iterate Range you want to copy
    for row, row_cells in enumerate(New_Burden[source_range], min_row):
        for column, cell in enumerate(row_cells, min_col):
            # Copy Value from Copy.Cell to given Worksheet.Cell
            ws.cell(row=row, column=column).value = cell.value

for source_range, target_start in [('W7:W46','J2'), ('Y7:Y46','A2')]:
    copy_range(source_range, target_start)
```

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2 - openpyxl: 2.4.1 - LibreOffice: 4.3.3.2***