# How to paste into cell based on value - Openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Good morning all.

I'm in a situation where I have two Excel workbooks. The first has my source data, and the second I'm trying to paste the source data into.

My code searches for a particular cell with today's date in in the first workbook, finds the cells of data I require associated with it, then tries to paste that range of data into a second workbook.

The code is able to currently iterate over the first workbook and find the correct data, but the issue comes to when I try and paste the data into the second workbook.

If for example the data found is from A40:C40, it will paste into the second workbook at the same location (A40:C40). I need the code to iterate the second workbook and find the correct location to paste the data in based on another cells value.

To be clear, the location of the copy and the paste varies every day. I cannot use a fixed cell reference.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
import openpyxl
import datetime

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Online Log.xlsx')
wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook('Blank.xlsx')

sheet = wb['Weather']
sheet1 = wb1['Sheet2']

# Find yesterday in date format
today = datetime.date.today()
yesterday = str(today - datetime.timedelta(days=1))

# Find position of midnight position on today's DPR
for row in sheet.iter_rows():
    for cell in row:
        if str(cell.value) == (str(today) + ' 00:00:00'):
           Start_Coord = sheet.cell(row=cell.row, column=3).coordinate
            End_Coord = sheet.cell(row=cell.row + 3, column=9).coordinate
            for row in sheet[Start_Coord:End_Coord]:
                for cell in row:
                    sheet1[cell.coordinate].value = cell.value

wb1.save('file2.xlsx')
```

I've tried incorporating the following code to search for the relevant place to paste into the second workbook, but that doesn't work either.

```
for rows in sheet1.iter_rows():
    for cell in rows:
        if str(cell.value) == 'Paste Cell Below':
            Start_Coord_2 = sheet1.cell(row=cell.row, column=3).coordinate
            End_Coord_2 = sheet1.cell(row=cell.row + 3, column=9).coordinate
            for rows in sheet1[Start_Coord_2:End_Coord_2]:
                 for cell in rows:
                    sheet1[cell.coordinate].value = cell.value
                    print(cell.coordinate)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy paste column range using OpenPyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44928146/copy-paste-column-range-using-openpyxl)

Comment: Not quite. That example use s fixed cell reference, mine is dynamic.

Comment: @stovfl - Can you explain please? You can see I've tried using a variable in the second example of the code.

Comment: You have multiple misstakes: **1.** You have to break your loop after match and done. **2.** You uses fixed `column=3` and `column=9`. **3.** You copy from `sheet1[...` to `sheet1[...`. See at [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/PresentInsistentFonts)

Comment: The loops make this difficult to read. Find the cells, use the offset method to get boundaries. Then do pasting in a separate function.