# Using Python & openpyxl to copy 1 specific row from one excel spreadsheet to another

Tags: python, excel

I'm trying to take 1 row from a worksheet in Excel workbook 'A' and paste it to a specific row in Excel workbook 'B'. I've gotten this far but I'm stuck on the pasting process:

```
import openpyxl 

#Open source & destination files
survey_results = "Survey.xlsx"
wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook(survey_results)
form1 = wb1.worksheets[0]
row2 = form1[2]

backend = "analysis.xlsx"
wb2= openpyxl.load_workbook(backend)
input_sheet = wb2['Input']
row4 = input_sheet[4]


#Copy contents
for i in row2:
    for j in row4:
        input_sheet.cell(row = 4, column = j).value = i.value



#Save to new file
wb2.save('output.xlsx')
```

Comment: may be problem at `row2 = form1[2]` It might be the same as `row2 = form1.rows[2]` then row4...

Comment: Use this approach [Copy a `Range(['W7:W46'])` from one Worksheet to another Worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44935521/7414759)

Comment: You're asking how to write data using openpyxl?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to automate the cutting/pasting of 1 row between 2 workbooks, then save it as a new workbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import openpyxl 

#Open source & destination files
survey_results = "Survey.xlsx"
wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook(survey_results)
ws1 = wb1.worksheets[0]

backend = "analysis.xlsx"
wb2 = openpyxl.load_workbook(backend)
input_sheet = wb2['Input']

# Copy contents
for c in range(1,ws1.max_column+1):
    input_sheet.cell(4,c).value = ws1.cell(2,c).value

wb2.save("output.xlsx")
```

Comment: Ugh! I was so close yet so far! Thanks for the help :-)