# Openpyxl - combine matching rows of two tables into one long row

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, openpyxl

In an Excel file I have two large tables. Table A ("Dissection", 409 rows x 25 cols) contains unique entries, each separated by a unique ID. Table B ("Dissection", 234 rows x 39 columns) uses the ID of Table A in the first cell and extends it. To analyze the data in Minitab, all data must be in a single long row, meaning the values of "Damage" have to follow "Dissection". The whole thing looks like this:

```
Table A - i.e. Dissection
- ID1 [valueTabA] [valueTabA]
- ID2 [valueTabA] [valueTabA]
- ID3 [valueTabA] [valueTabA]
- ID4 [valueTabA] [valueTabA]

Table B - i.e. Damage
- ID1 [valueTabB1] [valueTabB1]
- ID1 [valueTabB2] [valueTabB2]
- ID4 [valueTabB] [valueTabB]
```

They are supposed to combine something like this:

```
Table A
- ID1 [valueTabA] [valueTabA] [valueTabB1] [valueTabB1] [valueTabB2] [valueTabB2]
- ID2 [valueTabA] [valueTabA]
- ID3 [valueTabA] [valueTabA]
- ID4 [valueTabA] [valueTabA] [valueTabB] [valueTabB]
```

What is the best way to do that?

---

The following describes my two approaches. Both use the same data in the same tables but in two different files, to be able to test both scenarios.

The first approach uses a file, where both tables are in the same worksheet, the second uses a file where both tables are in different worksheets.

---

1. Scenario: both tables are in the same worksheet, where I'm trying to move the row as a range

```
current_row = 415 # start without headers of table A
current_line = 2 # start without headers of table B


for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=415, max_row=647):
    # loop through damage

    id_A = ws.cell(row=current_row, column=1).value
    max_col = 25

    for line in ws.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_row=409):
        # loop through dissection

        id_B = ws.cell(row=current_line, column=1).value

        if id_A == id_B:
            copy_range = ((ws.cell(row=current_line, column=2)).column_letter + str(current_line) + ":" +
                          (ws.cell(row=current_line, column=39)).column_letter + str(current_line))

            ws.move_range(copy_range, rows=current_row, cols=max_col+1)
            print("copied range: " + copy_range +" to: " + str(current_row) + ":"+str(max_col+1))
            count += 1
            break

        if current_line > 409:
            current_line = 2
        else:
            current_line += 1

    current_row += 1
```

-> Here I'm struggling to append the range to the right row of Table A, without overwriting the previous row (see example ID1 above)

---

2. Scenario: both tables are located in separated sheets

```
    dissection = wb["Dissection"]
    damage = wb["Damage"]
    recovery = wb["Recovery"]
    
    current_row, current_line = 2, 2
    
    for row in damage.iter_rows():
        # loop through first table
    
        id_A = damage.cell(row=current_row, column=1).value
    
        for line in dissection.iter_rows():
            # loop through second table
    
            id_B = dissection.cell(row=current_line, column=1).value
            copyData = []
    
            if id_A == id_B:
    
                for col in range(2, 39):
                    # add data to the list, skipping the ID
                    copyData.append(damage.cell(row=current_line, column=col).value)
    
                # print(copyData) for debugging purposes
    
                for item in copyData:
                    column_count = dissection.max_column
    
                    dissection.cell(row=current_row, column=column_count).value = item
                    column_count += 1
    
                current_row += 1
                break
    
            if not current_line > 409:
                # prevent looping out of range
                current_line += 1
            else:
                current_line = 2
```

-> Same problem as in 1., at some point it's not adding the damage values to `copyData` anymore but `None` instead, and finally it's just not pasting the items (cells stay blank)

---

I've tried everything excel related that I could find, but unfortunately nothing worked. Would pandas be more useful here or am I just not seeing something?

Thanks for taking the time to read this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the **2. scenario (one file, two worksheets)** but this code should be adaptable to the 1. scenario (one file, one worksheet) as well.

1. I copied the rows of Table B using code taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44928146/copy-paste-column-range-using-openpyxl).
2. And handled the offset with code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52813973/openpyxl-need-the-max-number-of-rows-in-a-column-that-has-data-in-excel).

Also, I added a few extras to my solution to make it more generic:

```
import openpyxl, os
from openpyxl.utils import range_boundaries

# Introduction
print("Welcome!\n[!] Advice: Always have a backup of the file you want to sort.\n[+] Please put the file to be sorted in the same directory as this program.")
print("[+] This program assumes that the value to be sorted by is located in the first column of the outgoing table.")

# File listing
while True:
    files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f)]
    valid_types = ["xlsx", "xltx", "xlt", "xls"]
    print("\n[+] Current directory: " + os.getcwd())
    print("[+] Excel files in the current directory: ")
    for f in files:
        if str(f).split(".")[1] in valid_types:
            print(f)
    file = input("\nWhich file would you like to sort: ")
    try:
        ending = file.split(".")[1]
    except IndexError:
        print("please only enter excel files.")
        continue
    if ending in valid_types:
        break
    else:
        print("Please only enter excel files")
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)

# Handling Worksheets
print("\nAvailable Worksheets: " + str(wb.sheetnames))
print("Which file would you like to sort? (please copy the name without the parenthesis)")
outgoing_sheet = wb[input("Outgoing sheet: ")]
print("\nAvailable Worksheets: " + str(wb.sheetnames))
print("Which is the receiving sheet? (please copy the name without the parenthesis)")
receiving_sheet = wb[input("Receiving sheet: ")]


# Declaring functions
def copy_row(source_range, target_start, source_sheet, target_sheet):
    # Define start Range(target_start) in the new Worksheet
    min_col, min_row, max_col, max_row = range_boundaries(target_start)

    # Iterate Range you want to copy
    for row, row_cells in enumerate(source_sheet[source_range], min_row):
        for column, cell in enumerate(row_cells, min_col):
            # Copy Value from Copy.Cell to given Worksheet.Cell
            target_sheet.cell(row=row, column=column).value = cell.value


def ask_yes_no(prompt):
    """
    :param prompt: The question to be asked
    :return: Value to check
    """
    while True:
        answer = input(prompt + " (y/n): ")

        if answer == "y":
            return True
        elif answer == "n":
            return False

        print("Please only enter y or n.")


def ask_integer(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            answer = int(input(prompt + ": "))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Please only enter integers (e.g. 1, 2 or 3).")
    return answer


def scan_empty(index):
    print("Scanning for empty cells...")
    scan, fill = False, False
    min_col = outgoing_sheet.min_column
    max_col = outgoing_sheet.max_column
    cols = range(min_col, max_col+1)
    break_loop = False
    count = 0

    if not scan:
        search_index = index
        for row in outgoing_sheet.iter_rows():
            for n in cols:
                cell = outgoing_sheet.cell(row=search_index, column=n).value
                if cell:
                    pass
                else:
                    choice = ask_yes_no("\n[!] Empty cells found, would you like to fill them? (recommended)")
                    if choice:
                        fill = input("Fill with: ")
                        scan = True
                        break_loop = True
                        break
                    else:
                        print("[!] Attention: This can produce to mismatches in the sorting algorithm.")
                        confirm = ask_yes_no("[>] Are you sure you don't want to fill them?\n[+] Hint: You can also enter spaces.\n(n)o I really don't want to\noka(y) I'll enter something, just let me sort already.\n")
                        if confirm:
                            fill = input("Fill with: ")
                            scan = True
                            break_loop = True
                            break
                        else:
                            print("You have chosen not to fill the empty cells.")
                            scan = True
                            break_loop = True
                            break
            if break_loop:
                break
            search_index += 1

    if fill:
        search_index = index
        for row in outgoing_sheet.iter_rows(max_row=outgoing_sheet.max_row-1):
            for n in cols:
                cell = outgoing_sheet.cell(row=search_index, column=n).value
                if cell:
                    pass
                elif cell != int(0):
                    count += 1
                    outgoing_sheet.cell(row=search_index, column=n).value = fill

            search_index += 1

        print("Filled " + str(count) + " cells with: " + fill)

    return fill, count


# Declaring basic variables
first_value = ask_yes_no("Is the first row containing values the 2nd in both tables?")
if first_value:
    current_row, current_line = 2, 2
else:
    current_row = ask_integer("Sorting table first row")
    current_line = ask_integer("Receiving table first row")
verbose = ask_yes_no("Verbose output?")
reset = current_line
rec_max = receiving_sheet.max_row
scan_empty(current_row)
count = 0

print("\nSorting: " + str(outgoing_sheet.max_row - 1) + " rows...")
for row in outgoing_sheet.iter_rows():
    # loop through first table - Table you want to sort
    id_A = outgoing_sheet.cell(row=current_row, column=1).value

    if verbose:
        print("\nCurrently at: " + str(current_row - 1) + "/" + str(outgoing_sheet.max_row - 1) + "")
        try:
            print("Sorting now: " + id_A)
        except TypeError:
            # Handling None type exceptions
            pass

    for line in receiving_sheet.iter_rows():
        # loop through second table - The receiving table
        id_B = receiving_sheet.cell(row=current_line, column=1).value

        if id_A == id_B:
            try:
                # calculate the offset
                offset = max((row.column for row in receiving_sheet[current_line] if row.value is not None)) + 1
            except ValueError:
                # typical "No idea why, but it doesn't work without it" - code
                pass

            start_paste_from = receiving_sheet.cell(row=current_line, column=offset).column_letter + str(current_line)
            copy_Range = ((outgoing_sheet.cell(row=current_row, column=2)).column_letter + str(current_row) + ":" +
                          (outgoing_sheet.cell(row=current_row, column=outgoing_sheet.max_column)).column_letter + str(current_row))
            #  Don't copy the ID, alternatively set damage.min_column for the first and damage.max_column for the second

            copy_row(copy_Range, start_paste_from, outgoing_sheet, receiving_sheet)
            count += 1
            current_row += 1

            if verbose:
                print("Copied " + copy_Range + " to: " + str(start_paste_from))

            break

        if not current_line > rec_max:
            # prevent looping out of range
            current_line += 1
        else:
            current_line = reset

wb.save(file)
print("\nSorted: " + str(count) + " rows.")
print("Saving the file to: " + os.getcwd())
print("Done.")
```

Note: The values of table B ("Damage") are sorted according to the ID, although that is **not** required. However, if you choose to do so, this can be done using pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("excel/separated.xlsx","Damage")
# open the correct worksheet

df.sort_values(by="Identification")
df.to_excel("sorted.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using `pandas` for situations like this. It is still a bit unclear how your data is formatted in the `excel` file, but given your second option I assume that  the tables are both on different sheets in the `excel` file. I also assume that the first row contains the table title (e.g. `Table A - i.e. Dissection`). If this is not the case, just remove `skiprows=1`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.concat(pd.read_excel("filename.xlsx", sheet_name=None, skiprows=1, header=None), axis=1, ignore_index=True)
df.to_excel('combined_data.xlsx) #save to excel
```

`read_excel` will load the `excel` file into a `pandas` dataframe. `sheet_name=None` indicates that all sheets should be loaded into an `OrderedDict` of dataframes. `pd.concat` will concatenate these dataframes into one single dataframe (`axis=1` indicates the axis). You can explore the data with `df.head()`, or save the dataframe to `excel` with `df.to_excel`.

Comment: I edited the question for clarification. I'm using two files (which contain the same data) to be able to test both scenarios. The first approach has both tables in the same worksheet, the second has the tables in different sheets. Your answer did concatenate the tables, however it pasted table B behind table A, without the sorting the rows of Table B according to the ID